# Instancof not working in drools rule engine drl file

Tags: drools, rule-engine, business-rules

i am passing a list `List<ArrayList> list = new ArrayList<>();` to drools  and the inner arraylist contains Objects of Class TaxPayer , and my rule is like

```
rule "test1"
when
    $l:TaxList($k : list)
    $b:ArrayList() from $k
    $a:Object() from $b
then
    if($a instanceof TaxPayer){
        $b.add(new TaxPayer(7,6,5,4,3,2,1));
    }
    if($a instanceof Object){
        $b.add(new TaxPayer(1,2,3,4,5,6,7));
    }

end
```

the second if is working fine, but it is not going in the first if even though it is an instance of TaxPayer

Comment: so i found the problem, the jackon doesn't have enough information about arraylist to serialize it, so it uses LinkedhashMap by deafult as its class

Answer (score 0):

I tried executing the above rule as :

```
rule "test"
when
    $c : TaxList($list : list)
    $b : ArrayList()  from $list
    $testobj: Object() from $b
then
    if ($testobj instanceof TaxPayer){
        System.out.println("inside if 1");
    }
    if ($testobj instanceof Object) {
        System.out.println("inside if 2 ");
    }
end
```

It is working fine for me. The output I am getting is :

```
inside if 1
inside if 2 
inside if 1
inside if 2 ...
```

Can you elaborate on your problem and add the respective java code to the question so that I will be able to understand how are you inserting the object into the drools session. Please add the Java code snippet and TaxList class.

**EDIT:**

**Main.java:**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        KieServices kieServices = KieServices.Factory.get();
        KieContainer kieContainer = kieServices.newKieClasspathContainer();
        KieSession kieSession = kieContainer.newKieSession("test");
        ArrayList<TaxPayer> taxPayers = new ArrayList<>();
        taxPayers.add(new TaxPayer(1));
        taxPayers.add(new TaxPayer(2));
        ArrayList<ArrayList> arrayLists = new ArrayList<>();
        arrayLists.add(taxPayers);
        TaxList taxList = new TaxList(arrayLists);
        kieSession.insert(taxList);
        kieSession.fireAllRules();
    }
}
```

**TaxList.java:**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class TaxList {
    ArrayList<ArrayList> list = new ArrayList<>();


    public TaxList(ArrayList<ArrayList> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }

    public ArrayList<ArrayList> getList() {
        return list;
    }

    public void setList(ArrayList<ArrayList> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }
}
```

**TaxPayer.java:**

```
public class TaxPayer {
    private int id;

    public TaxPayer(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

Comment: you can see here https://gist.github.com/uchia-itachi/6c11b68a3a79c305c55733a770c7ac10

Comment: From your code, I found that you are inserting TaxPayer object to the drools working memory whereas in the rule you are expecting a TaxList as an event. Try inserting TaskList in the working memory.

Comment: i passed the TaxList , but its still not working , can you show how did you wrote your client side code